# Oracle SQL Developer and Oracle 9i version

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer version: [image]

When i try execute a SELECT in a Oracle 9i database i got the following error:

[image]

I have PL/SQL DEVELOPER installed in my machine and i can SELECT this same table normally in same database (Oracle 9i) but with Oracle SQL Developer i got the error.

**SOLUTION**
I downloaded the driver ojdbc6.jar and set in Advanced Tool Oracle SQL Developer. Everything works fine.

Comment: Um... no, the error does not appear when you "try to connect". What you got is a normal Oracle error message, you wouldn't get that if you weren't able to connect in the first place. Just guessing, but I assume you get that error AFTER you connect, when you try to run a SELECT statement or something similar. If you work in information technology you should know you must be precise, especially when you ask for help. The issue is probably caused by a Java driver incompatibility with your very old Oracle version. See https://community.oracle.com/thread/3638852 for possible solution.

Comment: Exactly, this error occurs in SELECT not in CONNECT, i already edited my post.

Comment: I have a Instant Client 11.2 and tried: Tools > Preferences > Database > Advanced to point to an 11.2.0.3 Oracle client (either full or instant). But i got the same error.

Comment: I don't know much more than I already said (never had to work with Oracle 9). Lucky for you, Jeffy Smith, the program manager for SQL Developer at Oracle, is a contributor to Stack Overflow and he often jumps in to help on SQL Developer questions. Give him a few hours to find your post and respond to it! You did very well to tag your question properly with the `oracle-sqldeveloper` tag. Good luck!

Comment: What is the SQL statement you're trying to run?

Comment: If you're going to ask questions which only @thatjeffsmith can answer on StackOverflow maybe you should be asking them on [the OTN forum dedicated to SQL Developer tool](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/sql_developer)

Comment: @furman87, i think this is not important, because i can't change the SQL.

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas, just curious because that ORA error can be caused by many things, one of which is the SQL itself. I'm sure you have Googled it, but [here is a link to potential causes of the error](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01460_unimplemented_or_unreasonable_conversion_requested.htm).

Comment: I downloaded the oraclejdbc6 driver and putted in Advanced tool in Oracle SQL Developer. Every works now. Thanks

Comment: If you found a solution add an answer and _accept_ that answer. Otherwise this question will remain "unanswered"

Comment: Ready. I wrote the answer but i can't accept.

Comment: Just a warning. SQL Developer will eventually issue a JDBC call that is in the newer versions of jdbc. So while things look like they are working , something will fail this driver is quite old. If you have to have this old of sqldev, you may want to go get a very old version of sqldev that has this driver in it.   ( side note upgrade the db oracle 9 was ~ 2001 which by comparison is Windows XP times)

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

I downloaded the driver ojdbc6.jar and set in Oracle SQL Developer. Everything works fine.

[image]

Comment: You can download ojdbc6.jar from Oracle at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html